# How to Use Content-disposition for force a file to download to the hard drive?

Tags: html, download, httpresponse, content-disposition

I want to force the browser to download a `pdf` file.

I am using the following code :

```
<a href="../doc/quot.pdf" target=_blank>Click here to Download quotation</a>
```

It makes the browser open the pdf in a new window, but I want it to download to the hard drive when a user clicks it.

I found that `Content-disposition` is used for this, but how do I use it in my case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement Content-Disposition: attachment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875949/how-to-implement-content-disposition-attachment)

Answer (score 149, accepted):

On the HTTP Response where you are returning the PDF file, ensure the content disposition header looks like:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=quot.pdf;
```

See [content-disposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition) on the wikipedia MIME page.

Comment: @Oded : And in case the file is opened locally *(or any other cases without an http server)*?

Comment: @user2284570 - that would depend on specific browser and OS settings.

Comment: @user2284570 - don't know. Looks easy enough to test locally, no?

Comment: @Oded : did you looked to my last comment on the linked answer? The file isn't downloaded as HTML. There's also http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp, but I don't know it's JavaScript equivalent.

Comment: Very usefull for me, thanks, i spent hours to find why Chrome doesn't display pdf file into his viewer, the problem was that I return file in Respose like an attachment. So in my case for download a pdf in Response I used Content-Disposition: attachment; and for display a pdf i used Content-Disposition: inline;. Thank you very much for you answer.

Comment: Be careful: If your filename contains spaces, the latter segment will be truncated. Enclose the filename in quotes to avoid this. Quotes that happen to exist in the filename can be escaped by a backslash.

Comment: to force browser to download automatically, you will also need to set the content-type :  application/octet-stream; along with the content disposition

Answer (score 22):

With recent browsers you can use the HTML5 download attribute as well:

```
<a download="quot.pdf" href="../doc/quot.pdf">Click here to Download quotation</a>
```

It is supported by most of the recent browsers except MSIE11. You can use a polyfill, something like this (note that this is for data uri only, but it is a good start):

```
(function (){

    addEvent(window, "load", function (){
        if (isInternetExplorer())
            polyfillDataUriDownload();
    });

    function polyfillDataUriDownload(){
        var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[download], area[download]');
        for (var index = 0, length = links.length; index<length; ++index) {
            (function (link){
                var dataUri = link.getAttribute("href");
                var fileName = link.getAttribute("download");
                if (dataUri.slice(0,5) != "data:")
                    throw new Error("The XHR part is not implemented here.");
                addEvent(link, "click", function (event){
                    cancelEvent(event);
                    try {
                        var dataBlob = dataUriToBlob(dataUri);
                        forceBlobDownload(dataBlob, fileName);
                    } catch (e) {
                        alert(e)
                    }
                });
            })(links[index]);
        }
    }

    function forceBlobDownload(dataBlob, fileName){
        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(dataBlob, fileName);
    }

    function dataUriToBlob(dataUri) {
        if  (!(/base64/).test(dataUri))
            throw new Error("Supports only base64 encoding.");
        var parts = dataUri.split(/[:;,]/),
            type = parts[1],
            binData = atob(parts.pop()),
            mx = binData.length,
            uiArr = new Uint8Array(mx);
        for(var i = 0; i<mx; ++i)
            uiArr[i] = binData.charCodeAt(i);
        return new Blob([uiArr], {type: type});
    }

    function addEvent(subject, type, listener){
        if (window.addEventListener)
            subject.addEventListener(type, listener, false);
        else if (window.attachEvent)
            subject.attachEvent("on" + type, listener);
    }

    function cancelEvent(event){
        if (event.preventDefault)
            event.preventDefault();
        else
            event.returnValue = false;
    }

    function isInternetExplorer(){
        return /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;
    }
    
})();
```

Comment: It looks like it has fairly good browser support except IE 11 and mobile safari: http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Recent browsers support ES7 async/await and ES6 classes as well (except MSIE ofc.) Public sites can be optimized for MSIE while admin sites can be optimized for other browsers with new features. Or you can use an MSIE polyfill.

Comment: Widely supported now but note a same-origin restriction applies in most (all?) browsers.

Comment: Really useful the download attribute, it simplified a lot what I wanted to do, +1