# WebBrowser to open application/pdf

Tags: vb.net, browser

In my web-browser control, I am invoking a click.  I just loop through getElementsByTagName("INPUT") and for the submit one, I do obj.Click

All that button does is run a Javascript which does a postback by dynamically creating and posting a form with nothing more than ID=012345.

In Fiddler, the only thing that shows is that POST, though the return ContentType is application/pdf.  Exactly what I want.

The kicker is... my WebBrowser is opening that content with Adobe instead of in the control!  My goal is to save the PDF dynamically.  In IE when I manually click the button, it opens in-window.  If that were happening in my WebBrowser, I could save the document.  Or, if I could catch the application/pdf return somehow, maybe I could save that?

**Assumed Answer (Credit to Rick Mohr):**

My team, as confirmed by Rick below, assume that the WebBrowser control uses some 32-bit mode code.  So to fix the issue, you would have to be sure you are running your application with Platform Target: x86.

We didn't go through with it because this application interfaces with a lot of things, and we didn't see the ROI of the time to mitigate that. So I can't answer for sure, though I do believe Rick is correct.

So our solution was to use a one-off method using, something along the lines of HTTPWebRequest, to stream the object in. It isn't in-line with the rest of the project, but it certainly didn't break any dependancies, so it's good enough. :^)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195304/how-to-use-content-disposition-for-force-a-file-to-download-to-the-hard-drive

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Elchonon, but I don't have a URL.  The PDF is being dynamically created (probably by an ashx file on server-side), and sent back as a reply.  There's never a .pdf file.  But since it's returned as application/pdf, browsers can display them, or open them with adobe.  From there they can be saved.

Comment: My question has a header that says "This question may already have an answer here:..."  Is that just for me to see?  Or is that a suggestion by somebody?  That thread is talking about httpresponse and posting headers from a web-server somebody is building.  Completely unrelated.  I'm just using a webbrowser in vb.net to view a public website that I have no control over.  I can indeed READ their headers, which is how I got application/pdf as the content-type.  If there is a way I can use that in my WebBrowser control, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you on a 64-bit machine? The Adobe Reader DLL used by the WebBrowser control is 32-bit. When run in 64-bit mode it uses your Web Browser to open PDFs, as you're seeing. If you want it to work on a 64-bit machine, set your Platform target to "x86" instead of "Any CPU".

Comment: I'm not 101% sure that would fix it, though my team and I did assume that would be a solution.  We didn't go through with it because this application interfaces with a lot of things, and we didn't see the ROI of the time to mitigate that.  So I can't answer for sure, though I do believe you're correct.  We instead just used a side-method using something like HTTPWebRequest (not sure which route they went) to stream the object in.  It isn't in-line with the rest of the project, but it certainly didn't break any dependancies, so it's good enough.  :^)