# Download links click browser open download window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<a href="1.jpg" download="ImageName">download</a>
```

I have a download links, when user click it, I want browser open window and let user to chose location they wish to save, anyone know how to achieve?

(browser open window like when you use right click save as)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Use Content-disposition for force a file to download to the hard drive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195304/how-to-use-content-disposition-for-force-a-file-to-download-to-the-hard-drive)

Comment: I don't think this is what i'm looking for, 'browser open window' means when u right click on links, it open a window let you choose where you want to save, ex desktop

Comment: With the `Content-Disposition` header set as instructed, the browser will have to download the file, opening a dialog asking the user where to save it. You should notice that this dialog is configurable, as user may have set the files to always be downloaded to a specific folder.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the **Content-Disposition** response header to force the browser to download the file:

`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="<file name.ext>"`

More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9195376/1574059