# How to trigger a file download when clicking an html <a> tag or javascript in a modern browser

Tags: javascript, html, download, cross-browser

I would like to have an *a tag (anchor)* that triggers a download when clicked.

I've already tried all the solutions in this S/O question and more: 
[How to trigger a file download when clicking an html button or javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620698/how-to-trigger-a-file-download-when-clicking-an-html-button-or-javascript) and non works, except for this one:

```
<a href="lorem.gif" download="lorem.gif">HTML 5 Download</a>
```

This one works in the latest versions of Firefox and Chrome for certain file types, like images, but [doesn't work for PDFs and it doesn't work on IE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download) and many other browsers either.

Comment: @MaxZoom is a PDF or an image a malware? It is intended for commercial sites. Thanks for the opportunity to clarify it.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `Content-Disposition` HTTP header. You set it on the server-side when you are sending down the file:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=lorem.pdf;
```

It basically tells the browsers that they should download the file instead of trying to render it. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195304/how-to-use-content-disposition-for-force-a-file-to-download-to-the-hard-drive) or this Wikipedia page: [MIME#Content-Disposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition).

Answer (score 0):

Hrere is how to download the file

```html
<a href="lorem.gif" download="lorem.gif"><button>Download</button></a>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.