# How to trigger a file download when clicking an HTML Link <a> to other website

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I had read the following:
[How to trigger a file download when clicking an html <a> tag or javascript in a modern browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29688697/how-to-trigger-a-file-download-when-clicking-an-html-a-tag-or-javascript-in-a)

[How to trigger a file download when clicking an HTML button or JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620698/how-to-trigger-a-file-download-when-clicking-an-html-button-or-javascript)


For me isn't working.
I have a link to a file `https://childrensradiofoundation.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/2020_COVID19-_RemoteOutreach_Campaigns_English_D3.pdf` and I want to download the file:

```html
<a class="nav-link" href="https://childrensradiofoundation.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/2020_COVID19-_RemoteOutreach_Campaigns_English_D3.pdf" download>Download</a>
```

The code above open a new tab with the link and doesn't download the file.
Any suggestions with simple JavaScript if plain HTML not working?
I don't want a button (the link is in Nav Bar).

LATER EDIT: As @Lundstromski suggest bellow, there is no way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The link works as intended for me with a dummy file.

```html
<a class="nav-link" href="https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/02/file-sample_500kB.docx" download>Download</a>
```

Comment: You are right! But the file that I want is on a wordpress site.

Comment: Hi! Hmm, that shouldn´t make any diffrence. Is the link correct? I know its a dummy link in your post.

Comment: Im dont think its possible with a pdf: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794255/html-download-a-pdf-file-instead-of-opening-them-in-browser-when-clicked :(

Answer (score 0):

Its a error of that website that file does not exist!
Look here this works:

```
    <a class="nav-link" href="https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/02/file-sample_500kB.docx" download>Download</a>
```

Comment: @LucianDex yes I know is that link to file written correctly is there that .docx or .pdf...on the end?