# Force ie to Save file prompt

Tags: internet-explorer

I want to Force internet Explorer Always to ask save file prompt, also downloading pdf and also with some reader installed.
Someone knows what registry settings works for this purpose? Or any other solution?

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195304/how-to-use-content-disposition-for-force-a-file-to-download-to-the-hard-drive

Comment: Thanks but i cant work inside the html, but i need that when i download pdf the IE open the save prompt, i think needs some general settings that force IE in that way.