# How can i save excel file in downloads folder using asp .net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Below is my code to download the data in excel but the problem is while downloading it is not showing that the file is getting downloaded moreover i am giving the path in this way as given below to download the file in downloads folder but i should not use this because it works in local host but it will not work when hosted in server.how can i download into downloads folder with showing the downloading file at bottom

```
 protected void btnExportExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string pathDownload = @"~\Downloads\" Data.xls";
    ExportToExcel(dsExcel, pathDownload);
    lblMessage.Text = "Downloaded Successfully";
    }
    private void ExportToExcel(DataSet table, string filePath)
    {

   int tablecount = table.Tables.Count;
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePath, false);
        sw.Write(@"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"">");
        sw.Write("<font style='font-size:10.0pt; font-family:Calibri;'>");
sw.Write("<BR><BR><BR>");
            sw.Write("<Table border='1' bgColor='#ffffff' borderColor='#000000' cellSpacing='0' cellPadding='0' style='font-size:10.0pt; font-family:Calibri; background:'#1E90FF'> <TR>");
 sw.Write("</Table>");
            //sw.Write("<BR><BR><BR><BR>");
            //sw.Write("\n");
            //sw.Write(string.Format("Line1{0}Line2{0}", Environment.NewLine));


            sw.Write("</font>");

        }
        sw.Close();
    }
    this is the path that i am getting ~\Downloads\DATA.xls

    and i am getting this exception Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\11.0\~\Downloads\DATA.xls'. StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePath, false);
```

Comment: Short answer: You can't. You have no control over the file location of the client. And you are not creating an Excel file but a html page with an xls extension. Use a specialized library like EPPplus to create Excel files.

Comment: XLS file is a binary format, not a text one (possibly HTML format disguised as XLS?). You need to use third-party library to insert data into an Excel file then provide it to user (and even you can't decide where the file will be stored in client-side code).

Comment: [Renamed HTML files will now open in Excel](http://www.infoworld.com/article/3106774/microsoft-windows/good-news-for-microsoft-office-renamed-html-files-now-open-in-excel.html). If OP can open it locally it'll work as a download too.

Comment: could you please help me out as i am new to this

Answer (score 0):

Currently your streamwriter writes to a local file. You need to get it to write to the browser.  So instead of

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePath, false);
```

Use

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
```

Also, be sure to [set the right MIME type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974079/setting-mime-type-for-excel-document) and set the [content-disposition to trigger a download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195304/how-to-use-content-disposition-for-force-a-file-to-download-to-the-hard-drive).

Comment: Did you also set the MIME type and content disposition headers?

Comment: Did you follow the links?

Answer (score 0):

private void ExportGridToExcel()
        {

```
        Maingrid.AllowPaging = false;// To print all the pages without pagination in grid

        string filename = string.Empty;
        filename = "Report -" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfffff");
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename + ".xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);          
        Maingrid.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
        Maingrid.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;


        int x = Maingrid.Rows.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < Maingrid.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            GridViewRow row = Maingrid.Rows[i];
            //Apply text style to each Row
            row.Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");
            row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        }
        Maingrid.RenderControl(hw);


        string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
        //style to format numbers to string
        Response.Output.Write("<h1>Merchant Registration report</h1>");
        Response.Write(style);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }

    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Hi sivapriya thankyou for you respons it doesnot match with my requirement could you please look th code that i have posted

Comment: I have already gone through your code. There is no need to mention the Downloads path. Use the code which I have provided. That should work.

Comment: i am not at all having main grid in my code i have multiple grids where i am trying to download all the multiple grids in single excel sheet i kept your code but its giving me errors near main grid

Comment: Maingrid is the grid name I have used. You can replace with your grid name there.

Comment: int x = Maingrid.Rows.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < Maingrid.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            GridViewRow row = Maingrid.Rows[i];
            //Apply text style to each Row
            row.Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");
            row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        }
        Maingrid.RenderControl(hw);
  
  
  repeat the same condition with all your three grids