# Download (TIFF) instead of opening by default in Internet Explorer

Tags: download, internet-explorer-11, tiff

We are using Internet Explorer 11.  In one of our webpage we got an anchor link which is pointing to a TIFF file.  When I click the anchor link by default it is opening in the same page.  We want to download (dialog box to save) instead of opening in the same window.

Is there any configuration available in IE?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195304/how-to-use-content-disposition-for-force-a-file-to-download-to-the-hard-drive

Answer (score 0):

See the [Content-Disposition (RFC-2616)](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1) HTTP header, and use the value `attachment` (as opposed to the default value; `inline`):

> If this header is used in a response [...] the user agent should not display the response, but directly enter a `save response as...' dialog.

Example:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.tif"
```

See also [Content-Disposition (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition):

> The first parameter in the HTTP context is either `inline` (default value, indicating it can be displayed inside the Web page, or as the Web page) or `attachment` (indicating it should be downloaded; most browsers presenting a 'Save as' dialog, prefilled with the value of the filename parameters if present).