# Generate a download on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a webpage that has a csv form. I want to download csv file when I click the button and the window prompt is correct.

EX: I click the download button, a window prompt will popup I need to input "Hello" so that the authentication is correct, how do I download the csv form when input is correct and don't download when it is wrong. Thank you

here is my source:

## Code

```
<a href="#" class="download" onclick="myFunction()">Download</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.download').click(function(e) {
    var person = prompt("Please enter download access", "Hello Admin");
    e.preventDefault(); //stop the browser from following
    if (person != "Hello") {
        $('#auth__text').show();
        $('#auth__text__success').hide();
        document.getElementById("auth__text").innerHTML = "Wrong Access, You can't Download the CSV Data(s)";
    } else {
        $('#auth__text').hide();
        $('#auth__text__success').show();
       document.getElementById("auth__text__success").innerHTML = "You can now download the CSV Data(s)";
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: `window.location = "url of csv"`

Comment: window.location.href = 'file.csv';

Comment: That's a browser setting for .csv files - either show in the browser (what I'm assuming you mean by "reads the data") or download.  You can override this with server-side options.

Comment: How can I do that? @freedomn-m

Comment: Depends on your server-side tech, which you've not specified.

Comment: is there any other way that I can download the file on live server? @freedomn-m

Comment: This answer provides what you need to do - how you do it depends on what server you are using:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9195376/2181514