# i cant download minio generated link with a tag

Tags: node.js, express, minio

i'm trying to download a something from minio browser with "a" tag while using download attribute.
in this case i want to download a song, when i click on link, i redirect to play song page, but i see no download or save as pop up.
if i copy the link and past that in idm(internet download manager), start to download the file.

i set the bucket policy => read only for *

it is the download link that generated
https://5c6d9b4556185a0011c13b92.storage.liara.ir/singles/Ali%20Sorena%20-%20Aavaar(320)?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=V53B3X6JUVA1NSMG7SOAJ/20190417/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20190417T104438Z&X-Amz-Expires=604800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=39db9a3041d351b03c7b71b8a68d37f1729374e9008be9a68d378f88fb043b50

and a tag:

```
<a href="https://5c6d9b4556185a0011c13b92.storage.liara.ir/singles/Ali%20Sorena%20-%20Aavaar(320)?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=V53B3X6JUVA1NSMG7SOAJ/20190417/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20190417T104438Z&X-Amz-Expires=604800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=39db9a3041d351b03c7b71b8a68d37f1729374e9008be9a68d378f88fb043b50"
download>Download</a>
```

Comment: im usin this sdk https://www.npmjs.com/package/@liara/sdk#presignedUrl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add a `Content-Disposition` header to force download (see [How to Use Content-disposition for force a file to download to the hard drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195304/how-to-use-content-disposition-for-force-a-file-to-download-to-the-hard-drive)).

You can [apparently use the `reqParams` argument](https://github.com/minio/minio-dotnet/blob/master/Docs/API.md#presignedGetObject) to add `response-content-disposition`.

Something like this, maybe.

```
liaraClient.presignedUrl(
  "GET",
  "mybucket",
  "myfile.mp3",
  { "response-content-disposition": "attachment; name=myfile.mp3" },
  24 * 60 * 60,
  (err, presignedUrl) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log(presignedUrl);
  },
);
```