# Is it possible to make a download link for file on remote server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, download

Is it possible to create a download link for a remote file in plain HTML, or with JavaScript or jQuery?

The `download` attribute doesn't seem to work for remote files in Chrome 73 or Firefox 66.

```
<a href="//amazon.com/ads.txt" download>ads.txt</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the file URL must be on the same domain as the containing document, unless it's a `blob:` or `data:` URL:

> - This attribute only works for same-origin URLs.
> - Although HTTP(s) URLs need to be in the same-origin, blob: URLs and data: URLs are allowed so that content generated by JavaScript, such as pictures created in an image-editor Web app, can be downloaded.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's not possible. I would recommend using some sort of proxy-script on your server to overcome the cross-domains issues, like a simple PHP script. You can check referrer, add custom headers for content disposition etc

Comment: try this: https://gist.github.com/alpenzoo/c004eef71ce368e4fa2b56f3217eb6cf

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this client side.

The server hosting the resource you want to download can [provide a `Content-Disposition` response header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195304/how-to-use-content-disposition-for-force-a-file-to-download-to-the-hard-drive) which will trigger a download.

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=ads.txt;
```