# Download a file from a different internal server than the site is running from

Tags: javascript, html

I need to download a file from an internal server different than the one the site will be sitting on. I've tried the following...

`<a href="javascript:Start('file://servername/path/filename.txt')>`

`<a href="//servername/path/filename.txt" download="filename.txt">`

`<a href="\\servername\path\filename.txt" download="filename.txt">`

`<a href="https://servername/path/filename.txt" download="filename.txt">`

`<a href="ftp://servername/path/filename.txt" download="filename.txt">`

None seem to be working. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by internal server? Web server? FTP server? File server? Have you tried `href="file://servername...`. Is the problem with the path or the download attribute?

Comment: server where the file is accessed via smb or in windows \\servername\path\filename, and yeah I tried that and it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) says that the `download` tag only works :

> for same-origin URLs, or the blob: and data: schemes.

So you cannot make it work with the `download` tag

Comment: Thanks, is there a good way to make it work without the download tag, or must the file be stored in the same website directory?

Comment: You can always try to find workaround with JavaScript and by using the blob scheme with some fiddling.

Answer (score 0):

- Browsers generally block access to `file:` URLs from pages loaded over `http:` (or `https:`)
- Linking to files over Windows File & Print Sharing requires `file:` URLs
- The `download` attribute doesn't have any effect cross-origin

So:

- Use an `http:` (or `https:`) scheme URL
- Make sure an HTTP server is running on the target server
- Use [the `Content-Disposition` HTTP response header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195304/how-to-use-content-disposition-for-force-a-file-to-download-to-the-hard-drive) to mark the file as *for download*