# Prevent Mp3 From Playing In Browser PHP

Tags: php, audio, header, download

well currently I have a script which gathers mp3s. All the songs are hosted on external sites.

A user clicking the mp3 link will result in the mp3 playing in the browser in the users default audio player (quicktime etc)

I'm just wondering what code I could use (PHP) to have the mp3 open as a download prompt instead of playing. This would be easy although the catch is that it can't be processed through the server (aka can't use bandwidth)

can it be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance this appeared to be a duplicate of [How to implement Content-Disposition: attachment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875949/how-to-implement-content-disposition-attachment).

Then I saw the "3rd party sites" proviso.

There is no way to override the HTTP headers sent by a remote site when sending the client there. What you want is not achievable.

Comment: even by changing the headers via php then using header location or something?

Comment: @BelginFish Not as long as they're being served from external servers. If you want to download them and serve them from your own you could.

Comment: The headers would say "You can get it from Bob". The browser would ask Bob for it. Then Bob would say "Here is an MP3. Handle it however you like.". So no. You can't override Bob's information about how to handle the file.