# Open PDF (in IO.Stream) in WebBrowser Control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, pdf, stream, webbrowser-control

Please can someone advise how I can display a PDF in a WebBrowser Control.

The PDF is generated by exporting a Crystal ReportClass to stream using:

```
receiptStream = rpt.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat)
```

I have been trying to open this in a WebBrowser Control using `DocumentStream = receiptStream` but this just produces a page of rubbish.

I would prefer not to have to export the stream to file in order to display as this PDF is for transactional receipts, so this would be a large resource requirement.

Any help would be greatly apreciated.

Comment: You may want to try the [Data URI approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19288403/1768303). It did not work for IE10 last time I tried though.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion. With mine being a WinForms app, will this be affected by IE10 or does the webbrowser control pick up on the default browser?

Comment: It actually defaults to IE7 emulation, you'd need to use `<!doctype html>`, `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>`, and implement browser feature control:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18333982/1768303. Then it will use the latest and greatest features of whatever IE version is installed on the user's PC.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display PDF from a stream in a WebBrowser control](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3038043/11683)