# PHPExcel export gives me rubbish

Tags: php, phpexcel

So, i´m trying to make `PHPExcel` export som data from db and open a `Save dialog` for the user to save a excel file.

In my network preview i got this:

> PK%y~GGD²Xð[Content_Types].xml­MNÃ0÷"ò%nY
>   vAa   (0ö¤±êØgúw{&i@ÕnbEö{ßøyìÑdÛ¸l
>     mð¥×ÁX¿(ÅÛü)¿òF¹à¡;@1_æ»±Øc)j¢x/%êEày¦ ©QÄ¿i!£ÒKµy3ÜJ<§Z1½0?YÙL%zV
>   cäÖIb7Øûìa/lÙ¥P1:«qáríÍjªÊj0A¯Íuë""íàÙ(   ÁWìMä)Tjå({Ü²û>óOãÂ,XÙ­ÁÚÆ>Bÿ~×­ÏõÓ¤6ÜJ=¡oBZ¾°¼tìíX4Êú¾Cgñ,QgmrLÙÙ¯cïeëàtø± Zõ?´»hPvÃðÂ±úÿuÕjÀ¼Râæ¸øûî}¬CvÖøPK%y~G¶78éK_rels/.rels­ÍjÃ0ï{........

Just a lot of what?

And of course no `save dialog` opens.
I had this code working if i choose to save the file on server instead of open the "save dialog".

**PHP**

```
/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);

//Load phpexcel includes    
require '../Classes/PHPExcel.php';

/** PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007 */
include '../Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';

// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Add some data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'Nr');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B1', 'Höjd');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C1', 'Typ');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D1', 'Längd');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E1', 'AV');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F1', 'Öppningar');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G1', 'Vikt');


//Fetch data from DB
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE objekt_nr = '$objNr' ORDER BY length(element_nr), element_nr ASC";
try{
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $ex){
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}
//Insert on first row after heading 
$row = 2;
while($value = $stmt->fetch()){
    //Set start Column
    $column = "A";

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($column++.$row, $value['element_nr']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($column++.$row, $value['hojd']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($column++.$row, $value['typ']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($column++.$row, $value['langd']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($column++.$row, $value['avdrag']."");
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($column++.$row, $value['oppningar']."");

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($column++.$row, $value['vikt']);

    //INCREASE Row Nr
    $row++;
}

// Rename sheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle($objNr);

header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"results.xlsx\"");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");

// Write file to the browser
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save('php://output');

}
```

This works: `$objWriter->save('file.xlsx');`
And this gives me rubbish: `$objWriter->save('php://output');`

Why?

Comment: The sample you posted looks correct for a .xlsx document.  You should probably have a Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary header.

Comment: That "rubbish" is the __binary__ stream that comprises an xlsx document, a zipped collection of xml files.... look at the headers being received by your browser (and look at the headers being sent in PHPExcel's `/Examples/01simple-download-xlsx.php`

Comment: Your code works fine for me, when I corrected two things: I set the variable `$objNr` in Method `setTitle()` and removed the last curly brace. Then the file downloaded itself and could be opened in Office 2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting exactly what you asked for: a (zipped) XLSX document. However, your browser is probably not expecting that - you need to tell it "hey, this is not HTML, this is an Excel file!"

In your code, you have to send a [Content-Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212861/what-is-a-correct-mime-type-for-docx-pptx-etc) header, *before* any other output:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
```

and maybe also a header saying "you want to [save this as a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875949/how-to-implement-content-disposition-attachment)":

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $whateverFileName . '.xlsx');
```

You do have these in your code; however, you are probably sending something else to the browser before your code gets to those lines. Check that your script outputs *no* data (not even whitespace or BOMs - if your network preview has a hex view, like e.g. Fiddler, you should see 0 bytes sent in the response body if you don't call the `->save()` method) before it gets to the `header()` functions. See [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: Thank you. I will try to move these lines around. I´m calling the PHP file from ajax, so maby i must put the headers in another file to?!

Comment: That was no good. Now, i can´t even enter the page before the `save dialog`appears ;D