# Disabling button after form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

How can I change this function so when I submit form the button disables and page refreshes ?

```
function thanks() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    document.location.pathname = "index.php";
  }, 3000);
}
```

Page refresh function is working btw. I just need to disable button.

This is my form

```
<form  method="post" action="<?=htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8");?>?id={{$theme->id}}" id="myForm">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="price" value="{{$theme->price}}">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$theme->id}}">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="thanks()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>Buy theme</button>
</form>
```

**EDIT**

Problem is that whenever I disable the button the file doesn't start downloading.. why ?

Comment: _"so when I submit form the button disables and page refreshes"_ What is purpose of disabling button before page refreshes ? Is expected result for button to be disabled after page refreshes ?

Comment: Here's a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691054/disable-submit-button-on-form-submit

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/global-variable-usage-on-page-reload/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making it into an unobtrusive script:

```
<form  method="post" action="<?=htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8");?>?id={{$theme->id}}" id="myForm">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="price" value="{{$theme->price}}">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$theme->id}}">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="thanks()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>Buy theme</button>
</form>
```

And in jQuery:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function (e) {
  // do not allow to submit form
  e.preventDefault();
  // disable the submit button
  $(".btn.btn-success").prop("disabled", true);
  // do the set time out
  setTimeout(function () {
    document.location.pathname = "index.php";
  }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Works, but the problem is that file doesn't start downloading, do I need to put this: htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8");?>?id={{$theme->id}} somewhere in function ?

Comment: @feknaz Can you wrap your code between ` character? Edit the comment please?

Comment: @feknaz If you need some file to start download, you need to set headers: `header("Content-disposition: attachment");`.

Comment: In what place particulary should I place this line ?

Comment: @feknaz On the page where the download should begin. First of everything. `:)`

Comment: @feknaz Instructions for [client side](http://www.jtricks.com/bits/content_disposition.html) and [server side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875949/how-to-implement-content-disposition-attachment).

Comment: @feknaz Thanks boss. Let me know if you are stuck.

Comment: Yeah, I still don't know where to exactly put this line: `header("Content-type: application/force-download");`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102176/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-feknaz).

Comment: @feknaz Come to chat plz.

Answer (score 0):

Use the disabled property like this:

```
 document.getElementById("<button id>").disabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

On button click, set the `disabled` property of this button to `true`

HTML

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="thanks(this)">
```

jQuery

```
function thanks(elem) {
    $(elem).prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.location.pathname = "index.php";
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: This almost works. Button disables and page refreshes, but the file doesn't start downloading. The problem is whenever I add disable function to button the file doesn't start downloading