# Html - Open a link to a file in browser instead of download

Tags: html, file

This might be a basic question but I have a link to a file

```
<a href = "http://sitename.com/path/to/file.jpg">File Name</a>
```

I want to leave it a link, but when I click it the image just downloads. I would like for it to open in the browser instead of downloading. How can I do this? I feel like this should be easy, but for some reason I can't find the solution.

Comment: please show your complete code, the code above is not complete

Comment: Is it an anchor link? Is it coming from the server? What is it?

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653780/getting-a-file-to-download-instead-of-opening-the-browser?rq=1

Comment: Whoops didn't indent. Yes it's an anchor link.

Answer (score 2):

Your webserver isn't sending the right headers.

If you `curl -I http://sitename.com/path/to/file.jpg` you should see a header `Content-Type`.

The correct answer is:
`Content-Type: image/jpeg`

More specific answers are going to depend upon what webserver you're using.

Comment: I'm using Apache. The Content type is text/html. Strange.

Comment: Anything strange in your config? mod_headers, mod_mime, anything of the sort?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Is there a way to set the content-type header for certain files? I'm trying to look up how to do it