# Ruby on Rails' send_file takes forever for download dialog box to display

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have a ~40MB .wav file that users are downloading with the click of a button. The markup looks like this:

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <%= link_to "Download Single", download_song_path, class: "btn btn-default btn-custom" %>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <%= link_to "Download Artwork", download_artwork_path, class: "btn btn-default btn-custom" %>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And the controller is this:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end

  def download_song
    send_file "#{Rails.root}/public/white-flame.wav", :x_sendfile => true, :type=>"audio/wav", :filename => "white-flame.wav"
  end

  def download_artwork
    send_file "#{Rails.root}/public/white-flame-artwork.jpg", :x_sendfile => true, :type=>"image/jpg", :filename => "white-flame.jpg"
  end
end
```

The artwork download works fine, it's only a ~2MB file, but the .wav file literally takes 20 seconds or so just for the download dialog to display. What's the issue? I just want the user to be able to click "Download" and it download.

Answer (score 0):

The files are public, and there is no obvious logic in the controller which requires its use... Why not link directly to the file, so the webserver can handle it, instead of taking a round trip through rails, like so?

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <%= link_to "Download Single", 'white-flame.wav', class: "btn btn-default btn-custom" %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <%= link_to "Download Artwork", 'white-flame-artwork.jpg', class: "btn btn-default btn-custom" %>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: This just starts playing the track or shows the image, it doesn't prompt for download.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977159/set-content-disposition-header-to-attachment-only-on-files-in-a-certain-director

Comment: How do I set this on heroku then?

Comment: I haven't personally used a custom htaccess file with Heroku, but it does seem to be supported...

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your server to set their type as `application/octet-stream` or the browser will try to handle it.

I'm not sure about your `x_sendfile` code, so you should try it without that first.

Have you checked your application logs? `log/development.log` contains useful information.

Also try using `redirect_to` the resource instead.

Comment: This is hosted on Heroku, is there a way to set that up on there?

Comment: Try doing this: `send_file("...", type: 'application/octet-stream')`

Comment: :( Nope same issue, takes forever for download box to open (like 30 seconds to a minute)